# What are the drawbacks of using policy_any in openssl.cnf?

Tags: security, openssl, ssl, key-authentication, certificates

As given [in this document](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ca.html), we may use `policy_any` to ignore most of the fields of `subject` in `certificate request`. There must be some drawbacks of ignoring such fields, **would it may lead to some security related issues?**

The `policy_any` is given as:

```
[ policy_any ]
 countryName            = supplied
 stateOrProvinceName    = optional
 organizationName       = optional
 organizationalUnitName = optional
 commonName             = supplied
 emailAddress           = optional
```

What if I set `commonName = optional` and `countryName = optional` too? Is it a good idea to use `policy_any`?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Policy is simply a basic aid to tidying up and checking the incoming certificate signing requests follow corporate policy (or more precisely, your organisation's Certificate Policy (CP) and/or Certification Practice Statement (CPS)).

If you are signing your certificates on the command line, the security benefits are negligible - after all, you (or another user) could use openssl's `-config <filename>` option to use an alternative configuration file and bypass the above policy.  In this example, it might be useful to catch typos though.

On the other hand, if you're using this as part of a larger certificate authority where, for example, users submit a request via a web portal then this policy section might help you catch signing requests that haven't got all the fields required by your corporate policy.

That said, if set to `supplied` as in your example, it's not much of a check as it doesn't check whether the entries are valid or follow the corporate policy.  For example, it doesn't check for a `commonName` of www.google.com when your organisation is called acme.com!

Using `match` instead of `supplied` would help with some of the fields as you could, for example, enforce that `organizationalUnit` is consistent across your organisation's certificates.  However, you couldn't use `match` on the `commonName` field as that is expected to change in each certificate.

Name Constraints may help you there for certain certificate profiles.

In your example, changing `commonName` and `countryName` to `optional` would simply stop them being mandatory.

Note that fields that aren't in that list are silently removed from the signed certificate.  That is, if your request had the `generationQualifier` field set to `III` it would be removed from the certificate (unless you use the `preserveDN` option).

The list you have in your question is merely an example from the documentation pages of the most commonly used fields. There are many more possible fields that you could use, such as `initials`, `givenName` and `generationQualifier`.  Some are listed in RFC 5280 and if they aren't exacting enough for your needs, you can even define your own.  All that OpenSSL requires is at least one field to be present.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please explain in which cases CA may sign requests that haven't got all or none of the fields?

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by 'CA' - Commercial CAs operate very strict policies to ensure the integrity of their PKI.  You or I experimenting on a test machine would probably be at the other extreme of the scale and can configure OpenSSL with all sorts of unusual configurations.  A commercial CA wouldn't sign a request without a `commonName` field and neither would it expect all possible fields to be used (such as `generationQualifier`).  However, in your experimental lab, you can have a certificate with no`CN` (as long as you have at least one field)